# created a token and the supply is lower than i need

Tags: altcoin

I just want to create a supply of 70 billions but i have 70 millions.
Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

    /// @return total amount of tokens
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract BitcoinCrown is StandardToken { 

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   // Token Name
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
    string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
    string public version = 'H1.0'; 
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?

    // This is a constructor function 
    // which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
    function BitcoinCrown() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 70000000000000000000000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens.
        totalSupply = 70000000000000000000000000;                       // Update total supply 
        name = "BitcoinCrown";                                         // Set the name for display purposes 
        decimals = 18;                                                // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = "BTCC";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes 
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 2800;                                   // Set the price of your token for the ICO 
        fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                  // The owner of the contract gets ETH
    }

    function() payable{
        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

        //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your constructor function:

```
function BitcoinCrown() {
    balances[msg.sender] = 70000000000000000000000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens.
    totalSupply = 70000000000000000000000000;                       // Update total supply 
    name = "BitcoinCrown";                                         // Set the name for display purposes 
    decimals = 18;                                                // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = "BTCC";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes 
    unitsOneEthCanBuy = 2800;                                   // Set the price of your token for the ICO 
    fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                  // The owner of the contract gets ETH
}
```

You set `totalSupply` to `70000000000000000000000000 = 7 x 10^25`

You set `decimals` to `18` which means the total number of full unit tokens is:

`7 x 10^(25 - 18) = 7 x 10^7 = 70,000,000`

So you just need to add three more zeros to your `totalSupply`, or reduce the `decimals` value, however `18` is standard, so you probably shouldn't touch that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same number of decimals as there are `wei` in `eth`, so you could use this [unit converter](https://etherconverter.online/). When you plug in `70000000000000000000000000 wei`, that actually means `70000000 eth` or `70000000 BTCC` in your case.

Replace `70000000000000000000000000` with `70000000000000000000000000000` and you're good to go.

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to be looking at `wei` and `eth` conversion here. It happens that `wei` to `eth` is also `10^18`, but the real reason why this conversion is happening is due to the `decimals` property.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the answer to specify that the unit converter works only because he has the same number of decimals as there are `wei` in `eth`.